# wordpress - getting a blank page when submitting a comment

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

In functions.php I have this:

```
add_action('comment_post', 'comment_posted');

function comment_posted() {
    $MyClass = new MyClass(); //if I comment this line out the problem goes away
}
```

The comment gets posted successfully, but the brower gets stuck on a white page with a url that looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/wp-comments-post.php#comment-33
```

And in firebug I can see this: `405 Method Not Allowed`

I need to make calls in the MyClass php file, so I need that in there. I use that class in other functions within functions.php so I don't understand why it causes the blank screen in this case.

EDIT - The MyClass constructor:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->someVar='abc';
        mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "pwd");
        mysql_select_db("somedb");

    }
```

Comment: In Firebug can you see what HTTP method is being used to post the comment? GET, POST, PUT, etc

Comment: ...and how many comments do you have flagged as spam? If there are loads try to delete them (there's a "Clear Spam" button)

Comment: I see POST wp-comments-post.php and GET wp-comments-post.php#comment-33

Comment: What does the constructor for `MyClass` do?

Comment: Votey - when I comment out the 3 lines in the MyClass constructor, it works! Problem is that I need those 3 lines. Added them above.

Comment: any suggestions? this bug is killing me!

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen when dealing with PHP (regardless of whether or not it's Wordpress) is usually a sign of a PHP error. Have you [turned on your error logs](http://www.bradino.com/php/error-reporting/)? Do you see any error messages?

You say that you commented out the lines inside your constructor and it works. This causes me to lean to a database connection problem. Or, it could be that there is no class field, `someVar`.

Give those things a look and report back here. I'll help out as much as I can.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It's definitely not a problem with MyClass (it is used in other functions). Turning errors on gives me this: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/path/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:210)

Comment: Was there anything before that? That error usually follows another PHP error that was written to the page, which is the cause of the headers already sent message. Could you post both of your files?

Comment: Actually I just cleared up a php warning about an undefined variable. Now I don't get any warnings at all. I still get the blank page, and the comment still posts properly (I have to hit the back button to see it)

Comment: Try commenting out each line in your constructor, one at a time (start from the bottom) and see which one throws the blank page.

Comment: It's this line: mysql_select_db("somedb");

Comment: Check, mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "pwd"); The parameter order should be host, username, password. You have dbname. Are you using the correct credentials? Also, does somedb exist and does the user you're using when establishing the connection have permissions to access this DB?

Comment: yes, it is host, username, password. The credentials are fine - the connection is made and the email is sent out (which is what I'm doing when someone posts a comment). Everything works, it's just that I get the blank page.

Comment: What happens if you change mysql_select_db("somedb"); to: mysql_select_db("somedb") or die("It doesn't work");

Comment: Without access to all the files, that's all I got. Sorry pal.